# Работа с event Action, отписка от события

Tags: c#, unity3d, события, action

```
public event Action<GameObject> SelectCallbackMethods;

void Start()
{
    SelectCallbackMethods += (obj) => CharacterController.Instance.SelectObj(obj.gameObject);
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    SelectCallbackMethods.Invoke(this.gameObject);
    SelectCallbackMethods -= (obj) => CharacterController.Instance.SelectObj(obj.gameObject);
}
```

Как в такой ситуации можно отписать метод? Отписка, используя (-=) после Invoke не работает, метод все равно вызывается.

Правильный ли это подход использования ивентов?
Нашел решение: создание переменной для каждого Action, но имеет ли это смысл? Не то же самое ли это, если бы я просто вызывал метод в нужный момент из этого класса:

```
Action<GameObject> handler;

void Start()
{
    handler = (obj) => CharacterController.Instance.SelectObj(obj.gameObject);
    SelectCallbackMethods += handler;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    SelectCallbackMethods.Invoke(this.gameObject);
    SelectCallbackMethods -= handler;
}
```

Comment: Причина проста, в строчках с += и с -= генерируется 2 разных делегата: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLIN7LpGYYCmAbqQHYAumcMAPAPYBGAVqQMY0B86AZVIAbbjWwBDYcNYSuAawCypGgAtmwAM4BuZIWJQALIJoSATjQAUASn1ECSYk6dDRPSdNkLlajZvRgALzobOzogfxQcACclqHWuo7EAL56SURG6ADyVIrMAK6apACqAA42dugOzi4iYh4yckoq6loAdACSVOTM8qSWagCWmgmVzq71Uo3eLX7oALTBoeGRMXEco+noqUjJQA=== Таким образом, если вам нужно отписать делегат от события, у вас не остается ничего кроме как явно вынести его отдельным методом.

Comment: А имеет ли тогда вообще смысл использовать в таком случае ивенты, а не просто вызывать методы синглтонов в нужном месте? Action хранит ссылку на объект все это время?

Comment: Смотрите ответ. Мне кажется, что события и делегаты в вашем случае не нужны и, к тому же, несут дополнительные накладные расходы. Скорее всего, ваш код можно переписать с простым bool-флагом: в Start установить `handled = false`, в OnMouseUp написать что-то вроде `if (handled) return; handled = true; ...`

Comment: Как минимум второй вариант намного читабельнее, что не есть маловажно.

Answer (score 1):

Причина такого поведения проста: каждый анонимный метод компилятор разворачивает в отдельный метод.

Т. е. из

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public event Action<object> MyEvent;

    void Start()
    {
        MyEvent += obj => Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        MyEvent.Invoke(this);
        MyEvent -= obj => Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

получится примерно следующее

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private sealed class auxiliaryClass
    {
        public static readonly auxiliaryClass instance = new auxiliaryClass();

        public static Action<object> method1;

        public static Action<object> method2;

        internal void method1_Start(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }

        internal void method2_OnMouseUp(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }

    public event Action<object> MyEvent;

    private void Start()
    {
        MyEvent += method1 ?? (method1 = auxiliaryClass.method1_Start);
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        this.m_MyEvent(this);
        MyEvent -= method2 ?? (method2 = auxiliaryClass.method2_OnMouseUp);
    }
}
```

<sub>я опустил несущественные в данном вопросе детали, дословный код можно увидеть [здесь](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJabgdmQb2XWMwwFMA3MgOwBdsYAeAewCMArMgY1oD50AsgE8AolToBuZERJQALOgDKtAIYAnWgAoAlDOKEkJI4NHj6YALzo27dBf5Q4ATk03tUwyQC+0z8XnoAPLUAswArgDOZACqAA46eugGxiTCYjS0AHQAktQUzADWZJq0ABYAlhHuiUZpZugAtFY2dg7OrhzVfug+SF5AA)</sub>

Соответственно, при отписке от события, `method2` в нем не будет найден и это просто проигнорируется, `method1` так и останется в числе подписчиков.

Чтобы решить эту проблему вам нужно явно вынести обработчик в отдельный метод:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public event Action<object> MyEvent;

    void Start()
    {
        MyEvent += MyAction;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        MyEvent.Invoke(this);
        MyEvent -= MyAction;
    }

    void MyAction(object obj) => Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

<sub>[демонстрация](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJabgdmQb2XWMwwFMA3MgOwBdsYAeAewCMArMgY1oD50AsgE8AolToBuZERJQALOgDKtAIYAnWgAoAlDOKEkJI4NHj6YALwmocGFMMkAvtIfF56APLUBzAK4BnMgBVAAcdPXQDYxJhMRpaADoASWoKZgBrMk1aAAsAS39te2jiWLN0AForYRs7COckCPca2002Th50du10C34bAE42jiLkRyA==)</sub>

Ну или переписать код вообще без использования события, например, с простым bool-флагом:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public event Action<object> MyEvent;

    bool handled;

    void Start()
    {
        handled = false;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (handled) return;
        handled = true;

        MyAction(this);
    }

    void MyAction(object obj) => Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

Comment: Эта логика находится в скрипте Selectable, прикреплённом к любому объекту. Получается при отмене выделения - нужно будет переключать флаг всем выбранным, используя 
    GetComponent<Selectable>().selected=false;

Comment: Меня опять же в данном случае волнует вопрос производительности

Comment: @Ivan, в любом случае, подписка на событие и отписка от него более затратна, чем установка флага. Если я правильно вас понял.

Comment: А если учесть необходимость смены флага всех существующих,

Comment: В общем тогда при выделении придется дополнительно сохранять ссылку на все выделенные объекты, как объекты типа Selectable, чтобы потом при отмене выделения, переключать всем выбранным флаги обратно

Comment: @IvanIvanov, ну мне отсюда не видно, что у вас там происходит, я вам дал 2 варианта решения, выбирайте какой подходит вам лично. Если ответ решил вашу задачу — слева под кнопками для голосования галочка для принятия ответа.